# Is there a stable alternative to .Net's XmlSerializer which works for internal classes?

Tags: xml-serialization, xmlserializer

Could you point me to a stable alternative to the .Net XmlSerializer which supports serialization / deserialization of internal classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer` class. It supports internal classes but is less flexible. You will have to mark the internal class with the DataContractAttribute attribute.